# Unable to install Jupyter notebook extension in ubuntu 22.04 using mamba

Tags: deep-learning, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, ubuntu-22.04, fast-ai

**Unable to install Jupyter notebook extension in ubuntu 22.04 using mamba**

I have installed my deeplearning setup (jupyter, pytorch etc) using [fastai setup.sh](https://github.com/fastai/fastsetup/blob/master/setup-conda.sh).

I tried to install jupyter notebook extensions using the command :

```
mamba install -c conda-forge jupyter_contrib_nbextensions
```

But my terminal throws error :
[image: screenshot of the error in terminal]

[image: and this error also.]

What should i do ?

Thankyou.

Comment: This seems to work for Python 3.9, so I think it might be an issue for Python 3.10 and above (see also https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/issues/1650)

Comment: In fact, I also seem to be able to install it in a Python 3.10 environment, so maybe not!